# PHP issue with sleep() and redirect

Tags: php

I have the following dumb code:

```
<?

echo "<html><br><br><br><div id='loading'><p><img src='loader.gif'> Please wait 6 seconds...</p></div></html>";
sleep(6);
header('Location: http://google.com/');

?>
```

Why doesn't the HTML piece of code show up in the browser before sleeping 6 seconds and then redirecting? The codes doesn't output the HTML code at all, waits 6 seconds then sends me to the location. What do I do wrong?

Comment: you didnt do anything wrong sleep function is supposed to work like that

Comment: Won't work! headers would be already committed by the response from `echo`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would need to do something like (this won't work):

```
<?php

echo "<html><br><br><br><div id='loading'><p><img src='loader.gif'> Please wait 6 seconds...</p></div></html>";
@ob_flush(); //flush the output buffer
flush(); //flush anything else
sleep(6); //wait
header('Location: http://google.com/'); //redirect

?>
```

**However**:  This **won't** work as expected, **you cannot redirect the browser** after sending content (PHP will throw and error and tell you this)

Instead you should:

```
<?php

echo "<html><meta http-equiv=\"refresh\" content=\"6;URL='http://YOURURL.com/'\"><br><br><br><div id='loading'><p><img src='loader.gif'> Please wait 6 seconds...</p></div></html>";

?>
```

Where the `<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="6;URL='http://YOURURL.com/'">` tag is an HTML tag to tell the browser to change to the provided url after 6 seconds

To avoid adding the meta tag, you could also do this:

```
<?php
header('Refresh: 6;URL=http://www.YOURURL.com/');
echo "<html><br><br><br><div id='loading'><p><img src='loader.gif'> Please wait 6 seconds...</p></div></html>"
?>
```

But to be **safe** you should add both the header and the meta tag!

Comment: If you do that your header Location will not work since then headers were already sent.

Comment: You cannot send headers after the transfer of the content

Comment: I know, I wrote about this in my answer, perhaps you didn't reload before my edit about 1 min ago

Comment: Thanks all of you! You were very helpful, my code works flawlessly now.

Answer (score 7):

This will not work. Because the first echo will start output. After that header call will just fail. However you can do it with refresh header on PHP side.

```
<?php
header('Refresh: 5;URL=http://www.google.com/'); // refresh header
echo "<html><head>";
// meta refresh
echo "<meta http-equiv=\"refresh\" content=\"5;URL=http://www.google.com/\" />"; 
echo "</head><body><br><br><br><div id='loading'><p><img src='loader.gif'> Please wait 6 seconds...</p></div></body></html>";
?>
<script type="text/javascript">
// javascript refresh
window.setTimeout(function(){
    location.href="http://www.google.com";
},5000);
</script>
```

On the above script 3 things were handled.

1. HTTP Refresh header
2. Meta refresh
3. Javascript Refresh

**Note:** Meta refresh is [deprecated](http://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG10-HTML-TECHS/#meta-element) (though I have shown in example). HTTP Refresh header is recommended.

Answer (score 1):

From [PHP documentation](http://it.php.net/manual/en/function.header.php):

> Remember that header() must be called before any actual output is
>   sent, either by normal HTML tags, blank lines in a file, or from PHP.
>   It is a very common error to read code with include, or require,
>   functions, or another file access function, and have spaces or empty
>   lines that are output before header() is called. The same problem
>   exists when using a single PHP/HTML file.

So you can't use the **header()** function after **echo**.

I suggest you to use javascript or the meta tag instead.

Answer (score -1):

I think you are looking for `header('Refresh: 6; url=http://google.com/')`; to do redirect

buffering and script sleep is not needed.